# RegEx on CommonCrawl API filter parameter

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a regex in the filter parameter but I can't use the $ to determine the end of a string:

My request URL:

> http://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2017-39-index?url=*.com/&matchtype=domain&fl=url&filter=~url:.com/$

- my filter is using the `~` which makes it a regex
- validates correctly on a python regex tester: https://pythex.org/ for any .com URL, just TLD, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/

API documentation: https://github.com/ikreymer/pywb/wiki/CDX-Server-API#api-reference

I'm basically getting a lot of results with pages on each website which I don't care about, I just want the TLD.
If I take the `$` out it works.

Comment: Is `/` obligatory? Try making it optional, `/?`. Note that an unescaped `.` matches any char.

Comment: / is always there, so I want to use that as a marker for the end of the host name. Yes, door matches anything but that's beside the point since I've done that python regex test and it works. The point here is why isn't $ working..

Comment: I am afraid it is rather difficult to help without actually having the API at hand. Maybe it is just not supported. You may try other things like `\Z` (the very end of string) or `(?!.)` (no char is allowed after the current location), but I doubt these complex ones will work if `$` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work:
  `http://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2017-39-index?url=*.com/&fl=url&filter=url:.*\.com/$`

But in the future you may have to use `http://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2017-39-index?url=*.com/&fl=url&filter=~url:.*\.com/$`

1. there is a known bug in pywb [#249](https://github.com/ikreyme/pywb/issues/249). It's hopefully fixed and deployed to index.commoncrawl.org soon. As a temporary work-around: use `=` for regex filters and `=~` for "contains" filters.
2. `matchType=domain` is not required here as the URL is already matched by an wildcard pattern `*.com/`. It's supposed to query domain names, e.g. `http://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2017-39-index?url=commoncrawl.org&matchType=domain&fl=url`.
3. the regex is matched from the beginning of the field value, so it should be `.*\.com/$`. See the improved documentation in [pywb#250](https://github.com/ikreyme/pywb/).

Comment: For some weird reason, this doesn't work, only page 1: http://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2017-39-index?url=*.ie/&fl=url&filter=url:.*\.ie/$&page=1

Comment: Filters are purely secondary, it may happen that the second page (`page=1`) doesn't contain any entries/URLs matching the filter. The third page contains some: `http://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2017-39-index?url=*.ie/&fl=url&filter=url:.*\.ie/$&page=2` -- need to iterate over all [309](http://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2017-39-index?url=*.ie/&showNumPages=true) pages.